# Websocket: receive message from different page

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, akka

I'm new with websockets. My server side seems to be ok. The question about client.
  I'm trying to send message from one page and get it from another this way:

a.html:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/ws");
 $("body").on('click', '#some', function () {
        ws.send("clicked");
 });
```

b.html:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/ws");
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    var message = event.data;
    alert(message);
};
```

It doesn't work. I never get message on b. However when I combine this pieces together on one page it works as expected:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/ws");
$("body").on('click', '#some', function () {
     ws.send("clicked");
});
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
     var message = event.data;
     alert(message);
};
```

So what I do wrong? Should it works this way?

I use scala with play2, my server side code is (used [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWebSockets) manual):

```
def ws = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[String, String] { request => out =>
    MyWebSocketActor.props(out)
}

class MyWebSocketActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg: String =>
      out ! ("I received your message: " + msg)
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your server-side code for your webSocket?  If you want the message from one connected page to be sent to another connected page, it is your server that must make that happen.  Also, are both `a.html` and `b.html` loaded at the same time?

Comment: Added server-side code. Pages loaded manually in browser one after another with half-second difference.

Comment: What about your server side code makes you think that when it receives the first message that it will save it and then it will send a message to a page that loads sometime in the future?

Comment: I' m trying to figure it out now) Btw is my client-side ok?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, you are right, this is server side issue. Fixed now. I will complete my post with answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually server-side issue. Should use **tryAcceptWithActor** instead of **acceptWithActor**.